# Mostrar/Esconder informações animadas ao clicar no elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação

Gostaria de realizar uma simples animação que seja executada no evento de clique atribuído a um elemento. [Este é o site](http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/empresa.php) que usarei essa animação.

Suponhamos que meu elemento seja um um circulo, por exemplo. Quero que, ao clicar, ele fique maior e mostre algumas informações. Porém depois da execução, deverá haver um botão "Fechar" para que o elemento volte à posição original (menor, menos informações).

Como poderia fazer isto?

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework de JS ou você quer fazer isto com javascript puro ?

Comment: javascript puro, @fbadaro, tipow, eu tenho um "+" quando clicar aparece um background com info..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode facilmente fazer isto utilizando o [método `.animate()` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

## Exemplo:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class=container>
<div class=circulo>Mais</div>
<div class=close>X</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript(utilizando jQuery):**

```js
function mostraInfo(elemento){
 $(elemento).html("Carregando..."); //coloca o texto "Carregando..." no circulo enquanto realiza animação
  $(elemento).stop().animate({
    width: "200px", //propriedades a serem animadas (objetivo da animacao)
    height: "200px",
    padding: "10% 0 0 10%"
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    specialEasing: {
        width: "linear",
        height: "linear"
    },
  complete: function() {
    $(elemento).html("informação informação informação informação informação informação informação informação informação informação "); //exemplo de informacoes
    $('.close').show(); //mostra o botao de fechar
  }
 });
}

function escondeInfo(elemento){
 $(elemento).html(""); //limpa o html do elemento (as informacoes)
  $(elemento).stop().animate({
    width: "30px", //valores iniciais
    height: "30px",
    padding: "30px"
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    specialEasing: {
        width: "linear",
        height: "linear"
    },
  complete: function() {
    $(elemento).html("Mais"); //volta ao texto anterior "Mais"
    $('.close').hide(); //esconde o botao de fechar
  }
 });
}

$('.circulo').click(function(){
  mostraInfo(this);//executa funcao que anima aumentando o circulo e mostra informacoes
});

$('.close').click(function(){
  escondeInfo($('.circulo')); //executa funcao que anima diminuindo o circulo e esconde informacoes
});
```

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a6eN/1/)

Comment: poxa, muito bom , isso mesmo, tem como fazer um voltar, tipo um "x"

Comment: Tem sim, vou fazer e atualizar a resposta @Furlan

Comment: ta...vo esperar aki

Comment: pra faltar so falta o botao fechar;

Comment: Pronto @Furlan, mudei toda a implementação, separei em funções pra ficar melhor pra você entender, e coloquei o seu botão ali como um quadrado vermelho(voce pode alterar se quiser)

Comment: obrigado mesmo, isso que eu precisava!

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo utilizar jQuery, facilita o entendimento e você escreve menos e faz mais.
Fiz um código rápido e simples com base no que me passou:

HTML

```
<div class='conteudo-oculto'> 
    <div>Conteudo da sua mensagem</div>
    <span style='display:none'>Mensagem oculta</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.conteudo-oculto span { display none; }
.blue { background-color: blue !important }
.conteudo-oculto { display: block; width: 200px; height:200px; background-color: red; padding:15px; border-radius:200px; line-height:200px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer }
```

JavaScript

```
$( function (){
    $(".conteudo-oculto").click( function(){
        $(".conteudo-oculto div, .conteudo-oculto span").toggle();
        
        if( !$(".conteudo-oculto").hasClass('blue') )
        $(".conteudo-oculto").addClass('blue');
        
        else
         $(".conteudo-oculto").removeClass('blue');
        
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jt5r/1/)</kbd>

---

#### Versão 2

Veja se é isto (o HTML é o mesmo):

CSS

```
.conteudo-oculto span { display none; }
.blue { background-color: blue !important }
.conteudo-oculto { display: block; width: 100px; padding-top:15px; height:100px; background-color: red; padding:15px; border-radius:100px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer }
```

JavaScript

```
$( function (){
    $(".conteudo-oculto").click( function(){
        $(".conteudo-oculto div, .conteudo-oculto span").toggle();
        
        if( !$(".conteudo-oculto").hasClass('blue') ){
            $(".conteudo-oculto").animate({
                height:'200px',
                width:'200px',
                'border-radius': '200px'
                
            },1000);
            $(".conteudo-oculto").addClass('blue');
        }
        else {
            $(".conteudo-oculto").animate({
                height:'100px',
                width:'100px',
                'border-radius': '100px'
                
            },1000);            
         $(".conteudo-oculto").removeClass('blue');
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jt5r/2/)</kbd>

Comment: cara, eh isso mesmo, obrigado, como posso aumentar o tamanho do circulo oculto

Answer (score 0):

Sem usar javascript ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/riyazati/1/edit)):

```
<div class="circulo" tabindex="0">
  <div class="circulo--informacoes">Umas informações</div>
</div>
```

```
.circulo, .circulo--informacoes {transition: all 1s;}
.circulo {
  /* mude a vontade */
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 16px; width: 16px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circulo--informacoes {opacity: 0;}
.circulo:focus {width: 64px; height: 64px; padding: 64px;}
.circulo:focus .circulo--informacoes {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: como faço para ela abrir pra lado esquerdo, inves de ir pro liner, ou seja, ir para lado direito, mas quero que abra para o lado esquerdo

Comment: http://jsbin.com/riyazati/2/edit

Comment: eu pensei em tipo, dentro do circulo ter um  "+", ai quando clicar nele vai aparecer a msg normal, so que esse + rolar, virando um "X", e quando clicar nesse "X" voltar ao normal...sera q da?

Comment: Dá, *mas você parecendo meu cliente*. Por que não olha o código e tenta entender a ideia? Dica: use `transform: rotate(45deg)`.

Comment: ok, vou tentar, vlw gustavo rodrigues

Comment: tipo, como faço para o +, se transformar num x, transition?

Comment: @GustavoRibeiro, eu peguei um exemplo na net, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nxKpz
so preciso que ele pare quando girar....

Comment: Pegue um desse [exemplo](http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/navicon-transformicons/) e mude a posição das três barras para formar um +.